# How can I modify my batch file so it accepts input after the filename?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I created a batch file named "**query.bat**" that allows me to query a domain user account.

```
@echo on
set /p logonname=Enter logonname:
net user /domain %logonname%
```

Now, I'm wondering how I could modify the code so I can type "`query %username%`" then press **enter** instead of it being a two step process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To convert a `Set /P` variable to a passed in argument

You can use [batch arguments](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and pass the value of the logon name to the script as the first argument. You can then reference the *value* of the first argument with `%1`. You can simply change `set /p logonname=Enter logonname:` to be `set logonname=%1` in your script  instead.

### Script

```
@echo on
set logonname=%1
net user /domain %logonname%
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

  > %* in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. %1 %2 %3 %4
  >   %5 ...%255)  only arguments %1 to %9 can be referenced by number.